# Movimiento entre ramas de git

Tags: git, github

Tengo un problema con git. Después de haber inicializado el repositorio no consigo ver en local las ramas del repositorio remoto. Usando el comando `git branch -r` veo las ramas (en rojo).

¿Cómo puedo acceder a las ramas del repositorio para poder trabajar con ellas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normalmente** eso se hace utilizando ramas locales del mismo nombre, aunque no es un requisito:

```
git checkout blabla
```

Si esa rama *local* no existe, entonces git va a buscar los repositorios configurados en el local (`origin`, en este caso... pero podrías tener mas de un remoto) y buscar si hay un solo remoto que tenga una rama de ese nombre. Si es el caso, git entonces crea la rama *local* que le hace tracking a la rama remota del mismo nombre.

Usar ramas *locales* es lo ideal porque te permite hacer cosas en ellas sin perder los cambios. **Sin embargo**, utilizar la rama remota directamente sin una rama local también es posible:

```
git checkout origin/blabla
```

En este caso, git te va a colocar en la revisión en la que está esa rama trabajando *sin una rama local*. Esto se llama estar en `detached HEAD`. Esto te permite hacer todo lo que haces normalmente en git (merge, cherry-pick, commit, etc) *con la salvedad* de que no hay una rama local que esté moviéndose como normalmente sucede. Y es una de las herramientas más potentes de git (y tiene muchas herramientas muy potentes) ya que te permite *moverte* a una rama remota sin necesidad de crear una rama local.

Nota al margen: no hay razón para que coloques la imagen en la pregunta. Copia el texto y lo pegas en la pregunta. Si no lo sabes formatear, no hay problema, coloca el texto igualmente. Algún moderador se va a aparecer y la va a formatear de forma correcta.